# Write a method that takes in a sentence string and returns a new sentence representing its Aba translation

Tags: javascript, string

Beginner Coder and I'm confused if my include method is wrong. Maybe I should create an array and push the characters in? Am I on the right track?

Aba is a German children's game where secret messages are exchanged. In Aba, after every vowel we add "b" and add that same vowel. Write a method that takes in a sentence string and returns a new sentence representing its Aba translation. Capitalized words of the original sentence should be properly capitalized in the new sentence.

```js
function abaTranslate(sentence) {
  var words = sentence.split(" ");
  const vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou';
  var newStr = "";
  var char = words[i];

  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if (words.includes(vowels)) {
      newStr += (words + "b")
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(abaTranslate("Cats and dogs")); // returns "Cabats aband dobogs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split your sentence into individual words, as you're not interested in looking at the words, but rather the individual characters in the sentence. With this in mind, you can use the current loop that you have, and for each `i` grab the current character from the input sentence at index `i`.

If the current character is a vowel (ie: if it is included in the vowels string), then you know the current character is a vowel, and so, you can add the current character separated by a `"b"` to your output string. Otherwise, it if its not a vowel, you can just add the current character to the output string.

See example below:

```js
function abaTranslate(sentence) {
  const vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou';
  var newStr = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    var currentCharacter = sentence[i];
    if (vowels.includes(currentCharacter)) { // the current character is a vowel
      newStr += currentCharacter + "b" + currentCharacter;
    } else {
      newStr += currentCharacter; // just add the character if it is not a vowel
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(abaTranslate("Cats and dogs")); // returns "Cabats aband dobogs"
```

If you want to use JS methods to help you achieve this, you could use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression. Although, it's probably better to try and understand the above code before diving into regular expressions:

```js
const abaTranslate = sentence => sentence.replace(/[aeiou]/ig, "$&b$&");
console.log(abaTranslate("Cats and dogs")); // returns "Cabats aband dobogs"
```